# Using SlidingMenu with ABS Tabs working incorrectly?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I have Actionbar Sherlock and SlidingMenu set up in my project. I want the menu to slide in under the actionbar, so I set:

```
setSlidingActionBarEnabled(false);
```

Though, when I have the action bar Navigation Mode set up with tabs:

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

They stick with the action bar instead of sliding away. That causes the issue of being able to switch tabs and the view pager switching while the menu stays open. Along with it not being the aesthetic I am going for.

Is it possible for the tabs to slide away from the action bar with the menu? Or would it just be more practical to set up a custom implementation with radio buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to have the tabs slide when you are using NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS.

The alternative is to use the [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) library and the TabPageIndicator mode from that. That way the tabs are a part of the activity layout, and will slide. The downside is that the tabs won't get embedded in the action bar on larger devices or when a device is in landscape.

Comment: Well, what a dilemma then. I do like the tabs in the actionbar in landscape for smaller devices to give more vertical space. Makes me wonder if it is possible/practical to use both depending on size/orientation.

Comment: Yea that's a good idea to use both. It's a little more work, although ViewPagerIndicator should work pretty similar to the native tabs I think. 
So just have separate layouts depending on the orientation, and have you code work based on whether a TabPageIndicator view is present.